# ArcGIS Python Add in: Pass Entry from Combo Box (in Toolbar) to mdb

Tags: arcgis-10.1, python-addin, personal-geodatabase

How do you update the python addin wizard code to write directly into access or pgdb? I have a combo box and need to have my users enter data into the combobox to write into the database. Can someone provide an example of how to accomplish this task?

Comment: see [user profile for Bob C](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/23477/bob-c) for list of all duplicates (5).

Comment: Please edit the question to provide some detail. See comments on previous questions for what you need to provide.

Answer (score 4):

To try and understand your Question, I have reviewed the **[Creating a Python Add-In Combo Box](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//014p00000028000000)** help page to remind me that ...

> A combo box contains an editable field and a drop-down list. The user
>   can select a value from the drop-down list, which appears at the
>   user's request. If you make the combo box editable, the combo box will
>   include an editable field into which the user can type a value. The
>   scale combo box in ArcMap is a good example of a combo box.

If you are coming from a VB.NET background, then you may be thinking that a Python Add-In Combo Box can bind to an MS Access database as easily as a solution like **[these](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/382846/about-database-connection)** from another forum.

I have not had a requirement to try and work out the steps to do this using a Python Add-In Combo Box and ArcPy but am confident that **[Accessing data using cursors](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001q000000)** from the Data Access module of ArcPy (arcpy.da) will be required.

The example on the **[Creating a Python Add-In Combo Box](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//014p00000028000000)** help page does not include an editable field but that code could be:

1. Run through to learn how to update the combo box with the list of layer names
2. Adapted to learn how to update the combo box with a list of field values instead by using **arcpy.da.SearchCursor**
3. Adapted more to include an editable field and work with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor and **arcpy.da.InsertCursor**

If there is existing sample code available for including an editable field in a Python Add-In Combo Box and using it to update a Personal Geodatabase feature class then I am not aware of it.

Comment: Can someone delete this post!!!